# How to send field values to another website

Tags: php, javascript, html

I made a little site for car renting,but i dont understand very well javascript.
What i need is send the the values by my users enter in my input fields to a site, and that site will automatically tell the price of the selected car.

For example:

- car: Renault
- doors: 4
- aircondition: yes
- days: 9

Comment: Take a look at PHPs `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]` variables. They are the standard methods for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? make users submit a form, and just send that to the other site, pr process the values with javascript and send them using AJAx? Or is it a server side problem?

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this - and there's not really enough information to go on. Do you wish to obtain this info without sending the user over to the second site? If so you may need to do an XML call (on the server) or an AJAX call (via the browser). They are quite complex topics in their own right, and would require quite a bit of reading if you are willing to learn.

Comment: To be honest, i dont know what i want. The site where i send the values take the values from the web site name. Someone told me that javascript can do that. The page will just take the values i dont know how.

Comment: You can't make a request to another website using JavaScript. It's against its cross domain policy. Is your simple page hosted on a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example:

```
<FORM NAME="joe">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="burns">
</FORM>    
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">    
var locate = window.location
document.joe.burns.value = locate    
var text = document.joe.burns.value    
function delineate(str)    {
theleft = str.indexOf("=") + 1;
theright = str.lastIndexOf("&");
return(str.substring(theleft, theright));
}
document.write("First Name is " +delineate(text));    
</SCRIPT>
```

I found that code in this link:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471111/A-Quick-Tutorial-on-JavaScript-Variable-Passing.htm

Read that article carefully, it explains how to send variables and what is the difference between using javascript and using just html.

Answer (score 0):

If you will just redirect the users with their inputs to the site then you won't need javascript, just a form and you should name its fields as what the site expects them to be.

Answer (score -1):

Use a form

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

determine what type you want it to be (get or post) and have it send the form to the other site. Should look something like this:

```
<form action="http://www.sitetwo.com/thepage" type="post">
 ...form data input....
</form>
```

Your second site will have to be programmed to accept the input type and display the required content from the initial site.